# Hadoop Streaming error code 132

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, emr, hadoop-streaming, amazon-emr

I am getting `error code 132` in my streaming job. I have tested this successfully on a single-node (pseudo distributed) cluster. It somehow fails in the reduce step in the actual cluster.

**NOTE:** I am **not** getting `error code 1` anywhere. (error-code 1 suggests that something is wrong with the mapper/reducer code itself)

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 132
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 132
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

I also tried putting the reducer code in a try-catch block and printing the exception in case the code fails (i.e. fail silently) but the catch block never gets executed and the job fails.

**EDIT:** I am using AWS EMR to run my cluster (EMR version 5.5.0)

Comment: I hope you have the shebang line at the top of your script.

Comment: @philantrovert Yes, the shebang line is present. As I said, the job is succeeding on my local single node cluster.

Comment: can you add stdout and stderr logs from one of failed tasks? if you have hue installed, you can view logs there, or you can use `yarn logs` command https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#logs

Comment: update:you can also view logs from resource manager webUI (default port is 8088)

Comment: @ishan3243 Can you update your question with information about your cluster and how you are running the job?

Comment: @ishan3243: could you update the job submit command and reducer code?

Comment: @ishan3243 The update is not enough. As mrsrinivas said you need to update with your submit process how do you do that, your cluster configurations etc